# You have reached your question limit

Tags: support, post-ban

For many months now, I've been prevented from asking new questions here, on Stackoverflow - all due to the error:

> You have reached your question limit

Researching this error a few weeks back, I discovered the help page '[question bans](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)'. On it, I was informed that:

*The ban will be lifted automatically by the system when it determines that your positive contributions outweigh those questions which were poorly received.*

Since then, I've consecutively answered questions, had my answers up-voted and had my comments marked as helpful.. but still, I'm unable to ask questions due to the error message.

I came across the post '[What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)' which has lead me to believe that my question ban was caused by the automatic filter and therefore, cannot be undone by a human, however I'm wondering if a moderator is able to investigate this as I feel that I've done all I can to convince the filter to lift the ban.

Comment: You say you've been answering questions, but have you returned to your old questions and tried to edit them to be better quality/more on-topic/etc.? While answering questions _can_ in theory get you out of a question ban, fixing your old questions is more effective, if they can be fixed.

Comment: @Kendra I suppose I could try that, thanks for the tip

Comment: That tip is actually in the "What can I do" question that you link, under the "What can I do to release the ban" heading. Perhaps re-read that post, to make sure you didn't miss anything else that can help you.

Comment: Also, another quick note, if your question is about the Stack Overflow site alone and not the entire Stack Exchange network, you can ask it on [Meta Stack Overflow.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) Being question banned on Stack Overflow won't block you on Meta Stack Overflow, and you have the required 5 rep on Stack Overflow to ask on Meta Stack Overflow.